# How can I check if an order with a given increment id already exists in magento?

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento.

What's the proper way to check if an order with a given increment id already exists ?

The obvious way:

```
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($reservedOrderId);
    if ($order) {
        Mage::log('already have order with id ' . $reservedOrderId);
        return $order;
    }
```

does not work, because I get a new and empty model instance back.

What's the correct way in magento to see if I have no such model for that id ?

Comment: This should work. Are you sure your `$reservedOrderId` is valid increment id? Order increment id is a full order number you see in admin interface while inner order id (can be get with `$order->getId()`) is an actual entity id.

Comment: @Tim No it should not. The whole point is Thomas may or may not have a valid order IDs.  He's trying to determine that programmatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most common approach I've seen in core code just `load()`s a model and checks if there was a primary key assigned. In your case this would look like the following - note the very slight adjustment to the logical condition (`$object->getId()` vs. `$object`):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($reservedOrderId);
if ($order->getId()) {
    Mage::log('already have order with id ' . $reservedOrderId);
    return $order;
}
```

It's a simple mistake, but remember that *a call to load data on a Magento data model will always return the object instance*. It's only **if there is a result from the storage backend** that the object would be decorated with data and therefore a primary key.

Comment: Seems the most straightforward answer to me, and I actually tried the same thing before you answered.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience there are two ways to do this:

```
if ($order->hasData()) {
    // order already exists
}
```

or, by using a collection;

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $reservedOrderId);

if ($collection->count()) {
    // order already exists
}
```

In your case, probably best to use the first one.

Comment: Nice — I hadn't considered the hasData approach — glad that method's useful for something!

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways to approach this.  First, since you know the increment ID to expect, you could check for it after you get your model back

```
$increment_id   = '100000002';
$order          = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);

if($order->getIncrementId() == $increment_id)
{
    var_dump("Increment IDs match, that means there's an order");
}
else
{
    var_dump("Increment IDs don't match, that means there's no order");
}
```

Similarly, although there's a model returned even if there's no match, you could check that model's data — an empty array means nothing was loaded

```
$increment_id   = '100000002';
$order          = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);

if($order->getData())
{
    var_dump("Data array means there's an order");
}
else
{
    var_dump("Empty data array means there's no order");
}
```

Finally, you can load a collection with an increment id filter, and check how many items it contains

```
$increment_id   =   '100000002';
$c              =   Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('increment_id',$increment_id);        
if(count($c) > 0)
{
    var_dump("A collection with more than zero items means the order exists");
}
else
{
    var_dump("An empty collection means it does not");
}
```

I prefer the last approach for a simple "does/does-not" exists check, as a collection  doesn't trigger a model's after load method which means it's theoretically more performant.  That said, no approach is more valid than the other — just try to use the same technique everywhere for more readable code.

Comment: Alan, do you think your third approach is more performant than getId() from the other answer?

Comment: Since `$c` is a collection wouldn't `$c->getSize()` be even more _performative_ because it is less work for MySQL?  It is using `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of fetching the actual data.

Comment: @clockworkgeek Notice I said theoretically :) If performance was really a concern I'd say benchmark both methods, but looking at the source you're right, getSize would be (again, theoretically) a better choice.

Comment: if performance mattered, I would probably accept clockworkgeek's answer, as it's most likely the fastest.  It's a lot of code to write however, and not immediately obvious.

Comment: I like this answer (the first approach) the best. Simply checking for getId() not being 'falsey' on a loaded object doesn't sit well with me. Maybe I'm paranoid, but I really want be certain I've got the right data before doing anything.